# android app crashes before restarting

Tags: java, android, crash, runtime, logcat

My android app keeps crashing before restarting again automatically. When it crashes (after I press Run) the log cat is,

```
02-17 13:26:59.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1072): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-17 13:26:59.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1072): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to         instantiate application android.app.Application: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to get package info for com.example.con4; is package not installed?
02-17 13:26:59.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1072):     at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:509)
02-17 13:26:59.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1072):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4417)
02-17 13:26:59.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1072):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:141)
02-17 13:26:59.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1072):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
02-17 13:26:59.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1072):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-17 13:26:59.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1072):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-17 13:26:59.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1072):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
02-17 13:26:59.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1072):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-17 13:26:59.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1072):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-17 13:26:59.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1072):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
02-17 13:26:59.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1072):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
02-17 13:26:59.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1072):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-17 13:26:59.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1072): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to get package info for com.example.con4; is package not installed?
02-17 13:26:59.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1072):     at android.app.LoadedApk.initializeJavaContextClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:369)
02-17 13:26:59.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1072):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:322)
02-17 13:26:59.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1072):     at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:501)
02-17 13:26:59.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1072):     ... 11 more
```

It takes about 5 seconds before it comes back.

I have tried to research bits of the logcat but have many mixed results.

Is there any tips to make it work without crashing on runtime.

Comment: Please paste your code here.

Comment: There is quite a lot, should I include a dropbox file of the main activity?

Comment: Are you using an IDE to install the app or are you pushing it with adb? What happens if you push and then do "adb shell pm install -r /path/to/package-name.apk"?

Comment: I have the same problem on CM 11. I'm developing in ADT v.22.
Occurs when triggering 'Run' (Ctrl+F11), and if the app is in foreground.

Comment: I'm finding the same problem, but only if I've launched one of my Activities (which is in a different package) from an Intent specified in a Preference xml file. I've just taken all the code out of the Activity so it's completely blank, and still if I launch it, I get this on next restart from Eclipse. If I don't launch it, I don't see the problem. Odd. Still investigating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was, I was performing all the main functionality on the main GUI thread.

I did multi-threading, now it works.

Also one of the reasons it crashed on the AVD was the memory on it was small, before multi-threading, on an actual device it had no issues.